# Zombie vs Orphan process with sleep

Tags: process, child-process, zombie-process, orphan-process

I have the next code and I need to check the child process' status, but the sleep() confuses me. I think that the child becomes zombie for a period of time (until the parent finishes sleeping and waits). If this is correct, then what happens if the parent sleeps for 1 second instead of 1000? Will the child become orphan for a period of time?  Or is the process finished correctly since the parent waits?

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid) {
    sleep(1000);
    wait(NULL);
}
else {
   sleep(5);
   printf("Hello!");
}
```